# Fail to import H2O in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, h2o

The H2O had been installed in my PC but it's failed to import H2O before h2o.init() as the following screen shoot:
[Fail to import h2o](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WklZh.png)

Python is version 3.6.8 and h2o is version 3.18.0.2
Please advise me how to import h2o correctly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should install the latest stable version of H2O from the h2oai channel rather than the default anaconda package as well as making sure you didn't install a package called `h2o-py` which is a different package than the `h2o` package.

You can do this by running the following which is further described in the h2o-3 [docs](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/downloading.html#install-on-anaconda-cloud).

```
conda install -c h2oai h2o=3.22.1.2
```

where `3.22.1.2` is whatever version you are interested in.

Once you have gotten the correct version of h2o, `import h2o` should work. The last thing to verify is that you installed the version of h2o in the same conda environment that you are trying to import h2o.